# How to prove that a set is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

How does one, formally, prove that something is a vector space.

Take the following classic example: set of all functions of form $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$, where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that this is a vector space.

I've got a definition that first says: "addition and multiplication needs to be given", and then we need to prove some basic axioms, but I don't even know to start.... how do I know that multiplication and addition is ... "given". What does that even mean?

For example, I attempt to start by showing that $f(x)_1 \cdot c \in $ our set. What do I then formally say? That this EQUALS the following, or do we DEFINE it to be the following?

= $c(a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2)$.

Also, now I'd like to show that above is also an element of my set, which I can do by distributing the $c$ inside the parenthesis.... but how do I know I can do that? Also, this is precisely one of the axioms I later need to prove, but now I am already using it beforehand?

Comment: Addition and multiplication by scalars must be defined, this is what is meant by "given". Only then can you check the axioms. Your suggestion for $c\cdot f$ is indeed a good definition. How can you define the sum of functions?

Answer (score 1):

You prove that the sum of two elements in it is in it, and that if you multiply any element of it by a real number, you get a function still in it. Which is the case.

Answer (score -1):

The map $f: P_2(R) \to \mathbb{R^3}$ given by: $f(ax^2 + bx + c) = (a,b,c)$ is an isomorphism. Since $\mathbb{R^3}$ is a real vector space, so is $P_2(R)$.

Comment: This is probably not acceptable as a proof at the level OP is at (just having defined vector spaces). Besides, you cannot define a morphism of vector spaces before having checked that both sets involved _are_ indeed vector spaces. At best you could say the map $f$ from the _set_ $\Bbb R[x]_{<3}$ to $\Bbb R^3$ is a bijection that can be used to _define_ a vector space structure on its domain by transport from the structure of its codomain. But one would still need to check that it matches the given addition/scalar multiplication of polynomials.